Superconductivity and electronic bands
Textbook  BCS theory seems to be blind to the fact that the electron energy bands may "bend" or overlap, or the fact that the Fermi surface is not spherical because of the crystalline lattice. We know that the conductivity properties of a normal metal depend on the band structure (at least the bands close to the Fermi surface). How does a crystal structure (or Bloch states) influence the superconducting state?
Question: How does the band structure impact the properties of a crystalline superconductor? I can not find any clear reference.
Edit: the comment by @rpsml got the spirit of this question and pointed out this paper that I will try to read in the next days, Bardeen-Cooper-Schrieffer Theory of Superconductivity in the Case of Overlapping Bands (1959). Another related question is What is the difference of the gap between superconductor and insulator?

The standard textbook BCS theory, even on Wikipedia, references the Fermi level. That is a concept that only arises if you already know about electron energy bands.

@naturallyInconsistent Why do you say that?  There's a perfectly well-defined notion of Fermi level for, for instance, the free electron gas, which displays no band structure.

@march true, but a person who is dealing with BCS is already aware of the fact that actual crystalline solid superconductors have bandstructure, and that the Cooper pairing alters the bandstructure near the Fermi surface to produce a band gap. In fact, I'd point out that the QFE gas is a banded structure, just with all of the band gaps = 0.

Actually, BCS is a single band theory. It assumes that electrons are in one band, and that a gap will open in that single band. It does not take into account other bands. One should note that in a "boring" metallic band, electrons are quasi-free. So the free-electron description applies. The remaining of the band structure does not matter. If you are curious Suhl, Matthias and Walker [PRL 12, 552 (1959)] extended BCS to two overlapping bands.

@rpsml than you, your comment is very useful: I think you got the spirit of my question. In fact, I was thinking that there must be a case in which multiband effects are important: for example (I think) if the paring gap has a width that is comparable to the band width or band separation.

‘ conductivity properties are largely dependent on the band structure’ I don’t think this is true. A better understanding of metallic versus insulating behaviour comes from the Hubbard model.

@Quillo In fact multiband effects is very important in some cases. MgB2 and the whole set of iron-based superconductors are multiband. Essentially, superconductivity happens in 2 bands in MgB2 and in 5 in many iron-arsenide (look for the BaFe2As2 family). And the bands talk (electrons scattering) among themselves.
